# Developing Json services with node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Does it make sense to develop a rest service with node.js backed with mongodb? Is there a framework to make this easy like express?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use express? It implements all CRUD methods through:

```
app.get(...);
app.post(...);
app.put(...);
app.del(...);
```

In these function calls you can handle your mongodb queries and send JSON objects back to the client, if appropriate.

I hope I could help! :)

Comment: I thought express was for generating web pages, I am very new in nodejs area as you can see from my question :) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Like graydsl said express allready supports [these verbs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#http-methods). To parse JSON you would just use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and to stringify you would use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). I would use [Mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose) to talk to mongodb. Also to help you write clean code I would practice TDD/BDD using [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha). Finally I think you should have a look at [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent).